# Android notification always open MainActivity

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-notifications

After setting up Firebase, I receive a notification created with the Firebase console and when I click on it, my application opens the `firstactivity` declared on manifest.

I want to open a specific `detailactivity` that have the `firstactivity` as parent.

My manifest:

```
...
   <activity
        android:parentActivityName=".views.main.MainActivity"
        android:name=".views.detail.DetailActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".views.main.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
....
```

My custom FirebaseMessagingService:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(ProfileDescriptionActivity.USER_ID, 14);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(ProfileDescriptionActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent2);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(i);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

If I receive the notification when the application is closed, it correctly shows the notification in the notification tray. But when I clicked open, as say up, the `firstactivity`.

When the application was open and I receive the notification, into notification center was show a blank view that open correctly the activity that I want.

What is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You are probably doing some mistake with the type of push message (data or notification). Post the payload that your server sends to your app.

Answer (score 0):

To automatically open an application via FCM you need to use a `data-message`, which guarantees to always invoke the `onMessageReceived()` method.

For instance, your payload could be:

```
{
    "to" : "APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx...",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "great match!",
      "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "icon" : "myicon"
    },
    "data" : {
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
```

In order to test sending this message, you can use any online FCM tester such as [this](http://pushtry.com/).

Answer (score 0):

In FCM if your application is in foreground it calls **onMessageReceived** in **FirebaseMessagingService** , and if application is in background it automatically shows a notification as you declared meta-data in **AndroidManifest**.

So in this case you have to handle **onMessageReceived** and generate a notification.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // ...
}
```

If you want to handle both cases means if you want to handle both cases (background in foreground) don't send notification object in payload.
eg.

This cause **onMessageReceived** is not called if application is in background and called if application is in foreground.

```
{
    "to" : "APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx...",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "great match!",
      "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "icon" : "myicon"
    },
    "data" : {
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
}
```

Change this to like below payload and your **onMessageReceived triggered in both cases** if application is in **foreground and background also**.
**Just only send data payload not notification payload.
This can't be done by FirebaseDashboard, this can be only done by firebase api for send messages.**

```
{
    "to" : "APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx...",

    "data" : {
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
}
```